# recalling dropdown menu from mysql needs unique selections

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am learning PHP and MySQL and in doing so I am trying to do a little database driven website. I am tinkering with database driven dropdown form lists and so far can display them on the data entry form, can capture the result and insert it into database and now I am trying to recall the selected item, display it on the update/edit form. So far with the below code I can recall the data into update/edit form on a dropdown list however I want to narrow the selectable items down to just the unique roles.

My code is:

```
<?php

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/connections/connectdb.php";

$role_query = "SELECT fer_users.id fer_roles_id, fer_roles.description\n"
    . "FROM fer_users\n"
    . "JOIN fer_roles\n"
    . "WHERE fer_users.fer_roles_id=fer_roles.id";
$role_result = mysqli_query($connection, $role_query);
?>

<select name="update_role">
    <?php 
    while ($role_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($role_result)) {  
    $role_id=$role_row["fer_roles_id"];
    $role_description=$role_row["description"];
    $selected = ($role_row['fer_roles_id'] == $id);
    echo "<option value=\"$role_id\" ".($selected ? " selected=\"selected\"":"").">$role_description</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

The result of the SQL query is as follows:

```
id |     role
-----------------
8  | Administrator
16 | Administrator
9  |     User
14 |     User
15 |     User
```

And my drop down list renders as follows:
[image]

As noted above I need the list in the picture to just show Administrator and User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run two queries.

```
<?php

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/connections/connectdb.php";

$role_query = "SELECT fer_roles.id, fer_roles.description\n"
. "FROM fer_roles\n"
. "WHERE 1";
$role_result = mysqli_query($connection, $role_query);
$role_query2 = "SELECT fer_users.id, fer_users.fer_roles_id \n"
. "FROM fer_users\n"
. "WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."'"; //this assumes you're passing the user as a GET variable
$role_result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $role_query2);
$role_row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($role_result2);
?>

<select name="update_role">
<?php 
while ($role_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($role_result)) {  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $role_row['id'];?>" <?php if($role_row['id'] == $role_row2['fer_roles_id']){ echo 'selected="selected"';}?>><?php echo $role_row['description'];?></option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

May not be the most elegant answer but it should get the job done :)

Edit: the above is if you're trying to update one specific user. If you want a list of all users and their roles this would do it:

```
<?php

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/connections/connectdb.php";

$role_query = "SELECT fer_roles.id, fer_roles.description\n"
. "FROM fer_roles\n"
. "WHERE 1";
$role_result = mysqli_query($connection, $role_query);
$role_query2 = "SELECT fer_users.id, fer_users.fer_roles_id \n"
. "FROM fer_users\n"
. "WHERE 1"; //this assumes you're looking up a specific user
$role_result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $role_query2);
while($role_row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($role_result2)){
?>

    <select name="update_role">
    <?php 
    while ($role_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($role_result)) {  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $role_row['id'];?>" <?php if($role_row['id'] == $role_row2['fer_roles_id']){ echo 'selected="selected"';}?>><?php echo $role_row['description'];?></option>";
    }
?>
</select>  
<?php
} ?>
```

Comment: as a personal project no need for elegance, this worked 100% and I can piece and understand what is going on... that's all that matters!

Comment: @Matt: watch out for the first block of code - it has a SQL injection vulnerability in it. An absence of elegance is fine, but going into production with security flaws is (obviously) not. cc: Toby - can you fix?

Answer (score 0):

Add `GROUP BY fer_roles.description`

to the end of your query. This will group your results together by role description.

To include all of the IDs for each role, also change

`SELECT fer_users.id fer_roles_id, fer_roles.description`

to

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fer_users.id fer_roles_id SEPARATOR ','), fer_roles.description`

This will cause the `id` field to return a comma-separated list of each of the IDs.

Documentation on [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately that isolates the SQL response to just ID's 8 and 9 which means when I recall ID's say 14 and 15 their preselected dropdown menu item is "Administrator" not user. I am sure it is evident but I am trying to pull data from two tables if that helps?

Comment: thanks again, seem to be getting closer given the results. The exact syntax above generated an error but if I put a comma between fer_users.id and fer_roles_id it joint the ID's together but didn't generate an error... eg: as administrator is ID=1 and user is ID=2 the IDS were grouped as 81,161 and then 92,142,152.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $roles = array();
    while ($role_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($role_result)) {  
       $roles[$role_row["fer_roles_id"]]=$role_row["description"];
    ?>
<select name="update_role">
    <?php 
    foreach($roles as $role_id => $role){
       $selected = ($role_id == $id);
       echo '<option value="'.$role_id.'" '.($selected ? ' selected ' : '').'>'.$role.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: the fer_users table contains all the user details including one column called fer_roles_id. This column corresponds to the ID column of another table called fer_roles.

Comment: But all you need is role id and description, not users, right ?

Comment: no i need users id as well. This scenario is when I am recalling data from a database to update the record. So if a record has 1 (Administrator) under the fer_roles_id column then when I recall the record I want the drop down box to be preselected as administrator. In the picture on the original post you can see I can get the whole list to show, I just need to group the responses.

Comment: I hear you, and yet the problem is not the query, is the php code, i'm gonna updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: Hmm, try a var_dump($roles) before the foreach loop. you should see an array with unique roles

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting the ID returned to be the User ID, or the Role ID?

If the former, then you'd end up with duplicates as presumably there are multiple users with those roles.

If the latter, then wouldn't you want to modify the select to only look at the Roles table?

Comment: from what I can gather I need the User ID to obviously identify the user. I need the Role ID to ID the associated role and I need the Role Description to turn the number into a word on the dropdown menu